# How to change rootfs location used by Ubuntu.exe

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL enabled on my Windows 10. I've installed Ubuntu from Microsoft store and I can start it from Start > Ubuntu (the location of the executable is

`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2020.5.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc/ubuntu.exe`

Following [Winaero's tutorial](https://winaero.com/blog/export-import-wsl-linux-distro-windows-10/) I was able to create a new distro on a separate hard disk (D:) by exporting the default rootfs and importing it to a new folder at `D:\Wsl\NewUbuntu`. Now I can run Microsoft Powershell, type `wsl` and select my new distro as the default location.

My problem is when I run Ubuntu from Start > Ubuntu. That app always uses the old location (`C:\Users\myuser\Appdata\Local\Packages\CanonicalSomeCode\LocalState\rootfs`). How can I run Ubuntu.exe from my Start menu and make it use the rootfs from the new location at `D:\Wsl`?

Comment: @Biswapriyo thanks for the comment. Not sure if you've read my question though. Your link does not resolve my problem. I was indeed able to move the rootfs location and I am indeed able to run it from Powershell. What I actually want is for the Ubuntu.exe app to detect and use it.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4MSV6

Comment: Then make sure the distribution name is exactly "Ubuntu".

Comment: That seems to almost work, thanks! But now when I start Ubuntu.exe, I am logged in as root, not as my user. Any idea why this happens, or how do I get back to my username?

Comment: This may help https://superuser.com/a/1291457/726810.

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks! @Biswapriyo can you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it and award you the fake internet points? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question, OP has already moved the installed Ubuntu distribution to a
different drive. So, the answer starts with the next steps.

After registering the exported distribution, it can be launched with `wsl.exe -d`
command. But the Ubuntu.exe, the official launcher that comes with the Windows
Store package, first checks if any distribution name with exactly "Ubuntu" is
already registered. See `WslIsDistributionRegistered()` function call in
[DistroLauncher.cpp](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL-DistroLauncher/blob/master/DistroLauncher/DistroLauncher.cpp) to know more about the check. So, the newly registered
distribution must be named exactly "Ubuntu". For example,

- Register with this command:

```
wsl.exe --import Ubuntu <InstallLocation> <FileName>
```

- Set default user:

```
Ubuntu.exe config --default-user <UserName>
```

The distribution names are different for different Windows Store package. e.g.
"Ubuntu-16.04" is for [Ubuntu Xenial](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PJN388HP8C9) and "Ubuntu-18.04" for [Ubuntu Bionic](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N9TNGVNDL3Q).